# Java: Can methods with exception handlers not have return statements?

Tags: java, exception, return, try-catch

Can methods with exception handlers not have return statements?!?

-Below is the edited code.

```
    public int pop() throws NullPointerException {

    try{
         if (a.isEmpty()){
             throw new NullPointerException();
         }

         int x = (int)a.remove(a.size() - 1);
        if (x == (int)min.get(min.size() - 1)) {
            min.remove(min.size() - 1);
        }
        return x;

    }catch(NullPointerException n) {
        System.out.println("There are no elements to pop.");
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, defining exactly what method you're asking about

Comment: If you catch EmptyStackException, your return statement will not be reached. You need to specify what the method will return in that situation.

Comment: `throw new NullPointerException()`   Don't do that.

Comment: Think about what the method should return if the exception is thrown.  Then return that.

Comment: Ty. I'm posting the new code snippet in case someone needs a visual example in the future. Works the way it should.

Answer (score 2):

If `throw new <exception>` statement is always the last statement in the execution path through the method body or if the return type of the method is `void`.

In your code you could simply not handle the `EmptyStackException`. The problem comes from introducing `catch` that has neither `return` or `throw` statement at the end.

```
public int pop() {
  if (a.isEmpty()){
    throw new NullPointerException();
  }

  int x = (int) a.remove(a.size() - 1);
  if (x == (int) min.get(min.size() - 1)) {
      min.remove(min.size() - 1);
  }
  return x;
}
```

Comment: There is also the `throw new <exception>` in the `finally` block :(

Comment: Side note: [`finally` beats everything](https://ideone.com/bRdW8U) (except `System.exit(...)`, I know you said "*last statement of the execution path*", but `finally` is often overlooked).